# Define custom autofacs with Unity (Container abstraction)?

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container

In Ninject you can do

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(Func<,>)).ToMethod(CreateFunc).When(VerifyFactoryFunction);
```

This means with some magic and reflection you can do

```
public MyConstructor(Func<Type, IResult> factory) {
   this.result = factory(typeof(SomeType));
}
```

Instead of

```
public MyConstructor(IUnityContainer container) {
   this.result = container.Resolve(typeof(SomeType));
}
```

Is this possible with Unity? I did this extension method

```
public static void RegisterContainerAbstraction<TTo>(this IUnityContainer self)
{
    self.RegisterInstance<Func<Type, TTo>>(t => (TTo)self.Resolve(t));
}
```

You need to call it for all types that you want to abstract the container for, like

```
container.RegisterContainerAbstraction<IResult>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ninject allows is a bit a special feature and this is more of a functional approach. The DI libraries in .NET by default take a more object oriented approach which means that the support for creating and auto-wiring classes is usually pretty good, while the creation and currying of functions is supported poorly.

So, out of the box, there is nothing in Unity that will allow you to do this, but this can be easily solved by creating a custom interface and implementation:

```
// Abstraction: Part of your core library
public interface IFactory<TResult>
{
    TResult Create(Type type);
}

// Implementation: Part of your composition root
private sealed CreateFuncFactory<TResult> : IFactory<TResult>
{
    // Since we're in the Composition Root, its okay to depend
    // on the container here. See: https://bit.ly/1mdaLYG 
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    public CreateFuncFactory(IUnityContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public TResult Create(Type type) {
        return (TResult)container.Resolve(type);
    }
}
```

You can register this in Unity as follows:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IFactory<>), typeof(CreateFuncFactory<>));
```

Still however, if you apply Dependency Injection correctly, there is much less need for factory abstractions. They are still useful, but you probably need just a hand full in an application. So in that respect, instead of having one generic `Func<,>` or `IFactory<T>` abstraction, specify specific factories instead. This makes it much more obvious what is going on and since you should have a few factories this will not lead to lots of boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes, we only use it for our main API, like Command / Query handlers and other stuff that are close to the entrypoint for the DI. Still in a huge Enterprise system you are going to have some factories like this.

Comment: Also in a plugin based system where alot of invocation of types are done its nice to be able to abstract the container. Here is an example from one of my open source projects using ninject. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core/Plugins/PluginInvoker.cs#L49

Comment: @Anders: Exactly, you will have 'some' factories like this. Not a lot. Often the extensive use of factories comes from the fear of letting the container manage the lifetime of objects.

Comment: Yeah, but I still feel like I dont want to have the container too far away from the Bootstrapper (The place were you configure your bindings). Even if its only "some" placees. A solid use of DI and you can replace the container from Unity to Ninject or whatnot and it will  still compile and run after the Boostrapper is ported to the new DI

Comment: @Anders: I made that implementation private on purpose, because that keyword is only valid for nested classes. This way you can keep it in the same class.